# Simple C++ thread pool

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote a minimalistic thread pool using some C++11 features. I've used it on two projects so far and it has worked fine, but when I ran the code on my laptop, I believe that my thread pool might be entering some kind of dead-locked state -- occasionally the CPU activity drops to almost nothing, and the program hangs.

What are your opinions on the code?

My header file:

```
#include <utils/Uncopyable.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>


/// \brief Use this class to run tasks in parallel.
class ThreadPool : private Uncopyable {
public:
    ThreadPool();
    ThreadPool( size_t threads );
    ~ThreadPool();

    /// \brief Initialize the ThreadPool with a number of threads.
    /// This method does nothing if the thread pool is already running,
    /// i.e. ThreadPool( size_t ) was called.
    void initializeWithThreads( size_t threads );

    /// \brief Schedule a task to be executed by a thread immediately.
    void schedule( const std::function<void()>& );

    /// \brief a blocking function that waits until the threads have processed all the tasks in the queue.
    void wait() const;

private:
    std::vector<std::thread>            _workers;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>>   _taskQueue;
    std::atomic_uint                    _taskCount;
    std::mutex                          _mutex;
    std::condition_variable             _condition;
    std::atomic_bool                    _stop;
};
```

And my implementation is as follows:

```
#include <utils/ThreadPool.h>
#include <chrono>

ThreadPool::ThreadPool()
    :   _workers(),
        _taskQueue(),
        _taskCount( 0u ),
        _mutex(),
        _condition(),
        _stop( false ) {}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool( size_t threads ) : ThreadPool() {
    initializeWithThreads( threads );
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool() {
    _stop = true;
    _condition.notify_all();
    for ( std::thread& w: _workers ) {
        w.join();
    }
}

void ThreadPool::initializeWithThreads( size_t threads ) {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < threads; i++ ) {
        //each thread executes this lambda
        _workers.emplace_back( [this]() -> void {
            while (true) {
                std::function<void()> task;
                {   //acquire lock
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( _mutex );
                    _condition.wait( lock, [this]() -> bool {
                        return !_taskQueue.empty() || _stop;
                    });

                    if ( _stop && _taskQueue.empty() ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    task = std::move( _taskQueue.front() );
                    _taskQueue.pop();
                }   //release lock
                task();
                _taskCount--;
            }   //while
        });
    }   //for
}

void ThreadPool::schedule( const std::function<void()>& task ) {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( _mutex );
        _taskQueue.push( task );
    }
    _taskCount++;
    _condition.notify_one();
}

void ThreadPool::wait() const {
    while ( _taskCount != 0u ) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::microseconds(1) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few minor points, mostly related to coding style and practices:

- The non-copyable pattern is somewhat outdated since C++11 `delete`able methods. Some might also argue that explicitly deleting the copy constructor and assignment operator is more clear too. Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458874/1198654).
- Names starting with an underscore are somewhat contrived in the C++ language. For class members, this naming convention is not ilegal, but you might want to consider other options, such as the `m_` prefix or an underscore at the end instead. Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more on the subject.
- I would name `wait()` as `waitAll()` or similar, to make it explicit that it will wait for *all current tasks* to complete.
- In the implementation of `ThreadPool::wait()`, you should probably be using [`std::this_thread::yield`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) instead of `sleep_for`.
- You could go for an `auto &` in this loop:

  > ```
  >    for ( std::thread& w: _workers )
  > ```

  to facilitate maintenance if you ever change the contents of `_workers` by some other type.
- For absolute consistency, `size_t` is a member of namespace std, so it should be used as `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks OK, the only thing which may cause trouble is usage of the same mutex for queue locking and notification: it will be locked during `_condition.wait` and at the same time you are trying to lock it to add new task in the queue. Try to use separate mutex for condition and lock queue mutex in `initializeWithThreads` after condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Good point. I switched to a double-lock queue, and got entirely rid of the lock in the schedule-method. The occasional hang-up seems to persist, however, when using the minGW-w64 compiler, so the problem is somewhere else (I have no issues on linux).